# stats.field and stats.facet doesn't seem to be working right

Tags: solr, solr4

I'm storing a series of records that contain a `section_url` and a `count` fields.
I'm trying to aggregate by `section_url` and sum the `count` field, so I'm querying with the following params:

```
"params":{
  "indent":"true",
  "stats.field":"count",
  "stats":"true",
  "q":"section_url:tv AND domain:[* TO *] AND date:\"2014-12-22T00:00:00Z\"",
  "stats.facet":"section_url",
  "wt":"json"}}
```

As you can see, I'm running stats on the count field and stats faceting on section_url.
Most of the times this is working fine, but for some reason it's being buggy for some fields. For example, this result [My result](http://pastebin.com/065kdwgB)
As you can see, all the section_url's are `http://www.cb10.tv/` . However, for some reason my stats faceting seems to think section_url is actually two fields, `www.cb10` and `tv` instead of `http://www.cb10.tv/`

Any idea of what could be the problem?

Comment: What is the definition of the fields? Sounds like you're faceting on a tokenized field.

Comment: count is int, section_url is text_general, stored and indexed. I've tried turning it into a string but it didn't prove successful.

Comment: You'll need to reindex after changing the schema. You want that field defined as a StrField, not a TextField.

Comment: Thanks, I will try adding a copyField to a StrField for faceting purposes, and get back to you.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! You might want to add it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `section_url` is tokenized as you get several tokens for each entry. Faceting is performed on the indexed token, which means that you end up with a count for each token in the indexed content - and not for the content of the field itself.

Add a `StrField` (or a `TextField` with a `KeywordTokenizer`) and do a `copyField` to populate it (or change the existing field), and reindex your content. Use that field for generating the facet counts instead.